# Php version update on osx

Tags: php, wordpress, macos, updates

I am using wordpress to build an website with Jupiter theme, but it says my php version is too old.

So I tried to update php version from 5.3.3 to the higher version by following the guide on this site http://php-osx.liip.ch/ 
I updated to version 7, however when I get into the wordpress to activate the Jupiter theme, it still says I have php 5.3.3

When I type in $php -v on terminal it says I have the version 7, but it doesn't seem to work.

Can you help me to update php version to the higher version? It doesn't have to 7, but 5.5 would be good too.

Thank you!

[updated version check by php -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe2cL.png)

Comment: I am using Filezilla only.

Comment: Filezilla is an FTP client its irrelevant here, where are you running your site? Locally or on a server? If locally, on a Mac, where do you store your site files, what directory? Looks like you are running several PHP environments, my guess would be like MAMP or something similar, if so you need to update PHP there, and not OS X's default version.

Comment: If you're using FileZilla, it appears your site is being hosted somewhere else - You need to update php on that server, not on your personal computer.  What hosting provider are you using?

Comment: Oh.. I didn't know that. I just reached the hosting site and fixed it. Thank you all for your kind replies! :)